# Performing operations on a DataTable/DataView

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset, system.data.sqlite, amcharts

I have a Typed DataSet that is filled by `System.Data.SQLite` (using `SQLiteDataAdapter`).
I am trying to use one of the tables as the source for the Series of WPF amCharts Line chart.
I need to combine two of the columns (`[Year]` and `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName([Month])`) to use as the `SeriesItem` name.
I have been reading documentation on MSDN for hours with no success. Suggestions?

Comment: Can you use the || operator in your SQL before you pipe the data into your DataTable?

Comment: I forgot that I had asked this question. We have since switched to `PetaPoco` and I can not longer easily test any suggested answers.